# Need info with the Microsoft OAuth2 flow

Tags: azure, rest, oauth-2.0, oauth

I'm coding a project composed by an SPA and an API.
On the SPA, I have a button to link Google or Microsoft accounts to the user's account.
The API can whenever it wants call google/microsoft apis.

I've succeeded with google using the Authorization code flow:

1. From the SPA redirecting the user to https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/v2/auth with query parameters response_type=code and access_type=offline
2. Send the returned code to the API
3. The API call https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token to get an access_token and a refresh_token
4. Tokens are saved in the database, and can be used whenever the API wants.

==============

Microsoft has a similar authorization flow (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-auth-code-flow) but I can't use the authorization_code retrieved from an SPA into the API because of CORS policies.
I'm not using PKCE codes because tokens are retrieved from the API that use client_id and client_secret.

=============

Am I missing something ? Is it even possible to get an authorization_code from an SPA and use it to generate access_tokens and refresh_tokens from an external API ?

Thank you so much, sorry for my english !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the SPA, many authorization servers and identity providers do not support CORS requests, in such case, your option is to use the Azure AD  Implicit grant flow rather than the auth code flow, you can get the access token directly via the `/authorize` endpoint. This flow does not provide refresh tokens, so your app must be prepared to refresh these tokens periodically.

Reference - [Microsoft identity platform and Implicit grant flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-implicit-grant-flow)